# Passing additional params to Devise new_user_session_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter, omniauth

I am trying to implement Devise and Ominauth for multiple providers. One scenario is: user sign in with Twitter for the first time without creating an account first.

To handle this, I redirect user from callback link (`/auth/twitter/callback`) to sign up page to fill in email address.

However, I want to bring authentication information from the callback link `{:provider => "twitter", :uid =>"123"}` to sign up page (`new_registration_path`). Then when user submit sign up form, the authentication will be captured together with account information.

How should I go about doing this? I've tried

```
redirect_to(new_user_session_path, {:service => service})
```

where `service = {:provider => "twitter", :uid =>"123"}`
but service doesn't get passed through as a params.

What did I do wrong? Do I need to modify source code for Devise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probabbly looking for this:

```
redirect_to(new_user_session_path(:argument => "value"))
```

And in controller after redirect (probably UserSessions#new) you can access argument with:

```
params[:argument]
```

You need to pass arguments to path helper not to redirect_to method.

In your example it should be:

```
redirect_to(new_user_session_path(service))
```

And in controller after redirect (probably UserSessions#new) you can access argument with:

```
params[:provider]
params[:uid]
```

or

```
redirect_to(new_user_session_path(:service => service))
```

and

```
params[:service][:provider]
params[:service][:uid]
```